# Linux: snooping on existing process's output

Tags: linux

Say there's a running process that produces output, but you don't know where that output is redirected (it might go to a file, an open terminal, or `/dev/null` for all I know). Is it possible to snoop on existing process's output stream possessing only the PID of that process? Perhaps some way through `/proc`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command to see output of a running process:

```
tail -f /proc/$PID/fd/1
```

Comment: Does that aggregate all output? What if the process is outputting to multiple files? (interesting, +1)

Comment: This is for grabbing stdout/stderr only.

Comment: To redirect an already running process's stdout/stderr see: http://serverfault.com/questions/213119/how-can-i-redirect-an-already-running-processs-stdout-stderr

Comment: This works only if the output is redirected to a file. It does not work if the descriptor points to a terminal `/dev/pts/4`, and I did not bother calling `tail -f` on descriptor that points to `/dev/null`

Comment: Check the link I provided. Using gdb you can redirect a running process's stdout/stderr to any other place you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
lsof | grep $PID
```

Or

```
ps aux | grep $PID
```